# Prove the inequality $R+r > \sqrt{2S}$

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles

Consider a right angle triangle with sides $a , b, c$ with the inradius of $r$ and circumradius of $R$. Let $S$ be the area of the right angle triangle . Show that

$r+R > \sqrt{2S}$

I had tried my way by using Cauchy’s theorem  which resulted $r+R>\sqrt{\frac{abc}{p}}$. And I don’t know what should I do next .! Pls can anyone help me !

Comment: This is a hint for tackling a more general problem: by Carnot's theorem, $R+r$ is the sum of the distances of the circumcenter from the triangle sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with $$r=\frac{a+b-c}{2}$$ and $$R=\frac{c}{2}$$ and $$S=\frac{ab}{2}$$ we get
$$\frac{a+b}{2}\geq \sqrt{ab}$$ which is true.
it must be $$R+r\geq \sqrt{2S}$$

Comment: Is $$r= \frac{a+b-c}{2} $$ getting from $r=p-c$ because the circle is inscribed in the right angle triangle ?

Comment: yes this is the incircle radius

Comment: I was thinking too far! I used the formula $S= \frac{abc}{4R}$ and $S=pr$ which made the situation harder! Anyway thank you so much.

Comment: thank you for this nice problem